# Efficiant way to find related records using LINQ to sql

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I have a following data structure

- Articles
- Keywords
- ArticleKeywords (relationship between keywords and    articles)

I am trying to find a fastest way to find articles which are similar to each other, but I would like to avoid stored procedures.

This is what i have so far, but i think it can be done faster. I guess sending an array of INTegers as predicate parameter to sql is not optimal for sql query plan, and could be achieved with joins.

Any ideas?

```
//get original article. we will seek articles similar to this one
var article = await ctx.Articles.AsNoTracking()
                    .Include(m => m.ArticleKeywords)
                    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == articleId);

//get keyword ids
var keywordIds = article.ArticleKeywords.Select(m => m.KeywordId)
                .ToList();

//find articles with at least 4 same keywords
var related = await
                    ctx.Articles
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .WithSmallIncludes()
                        .Where(m => m.Active)
                        .Where(m => m.RootCategoryId == article.RootCategoryId)
                        .Where(m => m.Id != articleId)
                        .Where(m => m.ArticleKeywords.Count(akw => keywordIds.Contains(akw.KeywordId)) > 3)
                        .OrderByDescending(m => m.Id)
                        .Take(amount)
                        .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Create a view and execute it from the store procedure.

Comment: given article id, you only need query table **ArticleKeywords** to find related articles' ids.

Comment: @JojiThomasEapen i specifically wrote that I would like to avoid stored procedures.

Comment: you can use fetching 10 records at a time , and put it in a loop for searching , insted of getting all the datas. (XML make faster to get and insert data )